# Azure Function CI build

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Trying to setup CI for a series of Azure Functions (precompiled assemblies), but struggling. Newest VS2017.3 prerelease, with the Azure Function Tools extension installed and running TeamCity as build agent. Whenever I try to build the solution, I get a series of compiler errors:

[image]

If I compile the solution manually in VisualStudio, then the dependencies gets resolved correctly afterwards, when using the build agent. Fyi, I've added a nuget restore step with NuGet v4.1, but no luck.

Any ideas? Or maybe point me to a ps build script creating the final output structure (with generated function.json, folder structure etc).

Update: Output from nuget.exe restore step:

> [15:24:15] :   [Step 2/7] restore: Restoring NuGet packages for nhdb.sln (3s)
>   [15:24:15] :         [restore] NuGet command: C:\BuildAgent\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.NuGetRunner.exe C:\BuildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.4.1.0\nuget.exe restore C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\nhdb.sln
>   [15:24:15] :         [restore] Starting: C:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script1291459864204598526.cmd
>   [15:24:15] :         [restore] in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e
>   [15:24:15] :         [restore] JetBrains TeamCity NuGet Runner 8.0.46812.9
>   [15:24:15] :     [Step 2/7] restore: Restoring NuGet packages for nhdb.sln (3s)
>   [15:24:15] :         [restore] NuGet command: C:\BuildAgent\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.NuGetRunner.exe C:\BuildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.4.1.0\nuget.exe restore C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\nhdb.sln
>   [15:24:15] :         [restore] Starting: C:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script1291459864204598526.cmd
>   [15:24:15] :         [restore] in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e
>   [15:24:15] :         [restore] JetBrains TeamCity NuGet Runner 8.0.46812.9
>   [15:24:15] :         [restore] Registered additional extensions from paths: C:\BuildAgent\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\plugins-4.0
>   [15:24:15] :         [restore] Setting 'NUGET_PACKAGES' environment variable to 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages'
>   [15:24:15] :         [restore] Starting NuGet.exe 4.1.0.2450 from C:\BuildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.4.1.0\nuget.exe
>   [15:24:16] :         [restore] MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.3.409.57025' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.
>   [15:24:17] :         [restore] Restoring packages for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.VSM\AGP.NHDB.VSM.csproj...
>   [15:24:17] :         [restore] Restoring packages for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.BE\AGP.NHDB.BE.csproj...
>   [15:24:17] :         [restore] Restoring packages for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.LU\AGP.NHDB.LU.csproj...
>   [15:24:17] :         [restore] Restoring packages for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.SE\AGP.NHDB.SE.csproj...
>   [15:24:17] :         [restore] Restoring packages for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.DE\AGP.NHDB.DE.csproj...
>   [15:24:17] :         [restore] Restoring packages for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.NL\AGP.NHDB.NL.csproj...
>   [15:24:17] :         [restore] Restoring packages for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.UK\AGP.NHDB.UK.csproj...
>   [15:24:17] :         [restore]   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.framework/index.json
>   [15:24:17] :         [restore]   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.utilities.core/index.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.framework/index.json 552ms
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.framework/index.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.utilities.core/index.json 580ms
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.framework/index.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.framework/index.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.framework/index.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.utilities.core/15.1.548/microsoft.build.utilities.core.15.1.548.nupkg
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.framework/15.1.548/microsoft.build.framework.15.1.548.nupkg
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.utilities.core/15.1.548/microsoft.build.utilities.core.15.1.548.nupkg 12ms
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.framework/index.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.framework/15.1.548/microsoft.build.framework.15.1.548.nupkg 12ms
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.framework/index.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Committing restore...
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.NL\obj\project.assets.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Restore completed in 1,38 sec for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.NL\AGP.NHDB.NL.csproj.
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Committing restore...
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.BE\obj\project.assets.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Restore completed in 1,46 sec for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.BE\AGP.NHDB.BE.csproj.
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Committing restore...
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.LU\obj\project.assets.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Restore completed in 1,51 sec for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.LU\AGP.NHDB.LU.csproj.
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Committing restore...
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.SE\obj\project.assets.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Restore completed in 1,57 sec for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.SE\AGP.NHDB.SE.csproj.
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Committing restore...
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.VSM\obj\project.assets.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Restore completed in 1,62 sec for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.VSM\AGP.NHDB.VSM.csproj.
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Committing restore...
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.UK\obj\project.assets.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Restore completed in 1,68 sec for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.UK\AGP.NHDB.UK.csproj.
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Committing restore...
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.DE\obj\project.assets.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Restore completed in 1,74 sec for C:\BuildAgent\work\4921688dcda87d0e\AGP.NHDB.DE\AGP.NHDB.DE.csproj.
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] 
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] NuGet Config files used:
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]     C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]     C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] 
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Feeds used:
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]     https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore]     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
>   [15:24:18] :         [restore] Process exited with code 0

Comment: This definitely look like a failure to restore the WebJobs packages containing the assemblies where those types are defined. Did you validate that your restore is working as expected and pulling the WebJobs packages down?

Comment: You might be on to something. Based on the output from nuget restore (see above), it actually doesn't restore anything. Any idea why?

Comment: Without seeing your your project setup or packages.config file, it's a bit difficult to say. Do you happen to have this on GitHub or somewhere you can share by chance? Even if it is a small repro.

Comment: Any luck getting this working?

Comment: Update for VS (preview version!) solved the problem, I think.